# Problema "Allowed memory size of xxxxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xxxx bytes) in php" cuando despacho un job en Laravel

Tags: laravel, out-of-memory-error, jobs

Estoy teniendo problemas de memoria con Laravel jobs y las queues. El problema tengo me surge el siguiente. Estoy trabajando con imagenes tipo PNG, JPG y PSD. Estas últimas pesan mucho más, y tiene unas cadenas muy largas de tipo base64 que es el encode con el que trabajo.

Tengo preparados unos jobs que se encargan de coger los datos base64 recibidos por post y lo guardan en un fichero usando la función file_put_contents(En laravel Storage::put->....). Con los ficheros png y jpg todo trabaja correctamente. Cuando envío al job la data base64 da error de memoria y en algunos casos fallo al insertar el job en BBDD, pero he leído que la capacidad es brutal para un field tipo long_text.

```
 LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

Dudo que esté superando este tamaño ya que la imagen pesa unos 24 mb y usa de memoria 178 mb al recibirla por post y escribirla en un fichero.

Haciendo pruebas, el uso de memoria por php al manejar el psd es de 178 MB. Yo tengo en el php.ini memory_limit: 1 GB , max_file_size, post_max_size a 1GB también.

Se os ocurre que puede estar pasando?.

No tengo claro si puede ser un problema de memoria con las queues jobs que no aceptan estas dimensiones de string tan largas, memoria de estas queues?. Por el momento he dejado el script sin enviarlo al queue.

Información adicional: estoy usando una máquina de prueba de AWS amazon básica, un gb de RAM, para solucionar esto y que no fuera este el problema, he creado una unidad swap de unos 2gb adicionales pero el problema persiste.

Comment: Hola! No conozco laravel, pero lo que puedo ayudarte es con este enlace en inglés a un tema similar al tuyo: fíjate que en la respuesta aceptada ponen varios parámetros a revisar, aparte de los ya conocidos en PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit

Comment: Gracias me voy  mirar los parametros, lo que realmente he conseguido usando algunos de los parámetros que yo he puesto y los de ahí que funcione, el problema viene cuando yo mando esta tarea (escribir en el fichero la información) a hacerlo mediante un job en laravel. Parece como si no soportara la memoria.